# How to change the way I access an article object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, routes

My code is:

```
article_path(Article.first) - 'http://localhost:3000/articles/1063'
get 'articles/:id', to: 'articles#show', as: 'article'
```

I want to change it like this:

```
article_path(Article.first) - 'http://localhost:3000/articles/article-title-1063'
get 'articles/:id', to: 'articles#show', as: 'article' , id: /some_regex/
```

Comment: you might want to check `friendly-id`

Comment: And i think instead of `'http://localhost:3000/articles/article-title-1063'` you should go for `'http://localhost:3000/articles/1063/article-title'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by:

```
get 'articles/:article_title-:id', to: 'articles#show', as: 'article'
```

and create link or path as:

```
article_path(id: Article.first, article_title: "any-title-or-tag")
```

or

```
article_path(id: Article.first, article_title: Article.first.title.gsub(' ','-')
```

As you like, make sure that `article_title` param does not contain any spaces or other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set

```
get 'articles/:article_title', to: 'articles#show', as: 'article'
```

And in your `ArticlesController`, you get `article_id` from `params[:article_title]`.